# Framework/App for custom maps(not general google maps)

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

I've started to develop in Android 2 weeks ago and until now, I like it!
Currently I am working on a project where I have to display an individual map (not a google maps view, I'd like to display the map of a building's interior) with which the user can interact(mark positions, etc.).
Is there a framework or an existing app that I could use? Of course I searched the internet but could not find anything.
Perhaps it is in some way possible to use the google maps API?
I hope you can help me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at  [OsmDroid project](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/) - a very nice replacement of the Android's Google Maps library.

Hope this helps :o)